# HOME not set when running bash from rc.local

Tags: raspbian, rc.local

I have a line in `rc.local` to run a simple bash script upon boot. The operating system is Raspbian Stretch 4.14 on a Raspberry Pi 3B+, with a 'Witty Pi 2' power management board (UUGear).

```
bash /home/pi/Desktop/mount_and_run.bash &
```

The bash script does not seem to run, and `syslog` suggests the error may be related to not finding the file in the first place - there is no indication the bash file is even being read.  Here is a clue in `var/log/syslog`:

```
May 27 22:04:12 raspberrypi rc.local[417]: /home/pi/Desktop/mount_and_run.bash: line 30: cd: HOME not set
```

The Raspberry does seem to know what $HOME is (`/home/pi`) if I enter into the terminal:

```
pwd; echo ~; echo $HOME
```

I can also read the bash file on the Desktop using `nano`. I have not seen this before, on previous occasions the script has run fine from `rc.local`.    I would be very grateful for insights and suggested fixes, the installation of Stretch is fresh, and I have spent hours testing and investigating...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not about finding the script, the issue is that you rely on `$HOME` having a value in an environment which may not have defined this variable (the environment `rc.local` runs in).  `$HOME` usually only has a value after login (and in some other documented places, such as in cron jobs).

You rely on `$HOME` having a value either because you use it implicitly in `cd` (with no argument), or in a tilde expansion.

One way to fix this is by explicitly setting `$HOME` in the script:

```
HOME=${HOME:-/home/pi}
export HOME
```

This would set `$HOME` to `/home/pi` unless it's already set and non-empty.

Note that commands being run from `rc.local` is running as root. To run your script as a specific user, use

```
su username -c bash /home/pi/Desktop/mount_and_run.bash &
```

in `rc.local`.

You may even want to use `su -l username -c bash ...` which would simulate a full login, which in turn would set `$HOME` to the appropriate value for the given user.

Comment: You just can't beat the detail of Kusalananda answers, nice work!

Comment: Thank you @Kusalananda.  So, can I explicitly set ```$HOME``` as you have described in the two lines above my ```bash``` command in ```rc.local```?  I should mention that I am running my script headless, so no chance to enter my password after ```su```, and the default username in the Raspberry is "pi".

Comment: @ptenax You would set `HOME` in the script, definitely not in `rc.local`.  The root user does not have to give any passwords when using `su`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Okay, so explicitly setting HOME would be the first lines in my script ```mount_and_run.bash```  - but this file is not even being opened because it cannot be found?  I will try it and see!  My very great thanks.

Comment: @ptenax As I wrote, the script is actually found. The issue is that `HOME` is unset on line 30 in the script (see the error message) where you use either `cd` with no argument or `cd ~/something`.  Both of these require `HOME` to be set.

Comment: @Kusalananda Okay, thank you very much for your further explanation I understand better now.  My apologies, being new to Linux I catch on a bit slower.  I will follow your advice.  I also understand the answer of Panki better - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Everything listed in `rc.local` is run by `root`.

For some reason, it seems that the `HOME` variable is not set when running `rc.local` (which would lead to `/root/`, and I believe you want your regular users home under `/home/user/`).

To fix this, replace `$HOME` in your script with the full path, i.e. `/home/user/`.

Comment: Thank you @Panki.  I may be not understanding your answer..., but my command within ```rc.local``` already contains the full path ("pi" is the default username for Raspberries).  See my comment above also Kusalananda - I am still trying to understand.